# rails 4, ajax changing methods in form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm able to like something and update the like count on the first click, but it doesn't work on the second click. I debugged it where the post needs to change, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the form method on the ajax call.

**skit_controller.rb**

```
def like
  @skit.liked_by current_user   if request.post?
  @skit.unliked_by current_user if request.delete?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to skits_path, notice: 'Successfully voted!' }
    format.js
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :skits do
  resources :challenges
  match :like, via: [:post, :delete], on: :member
end
```

**index.html.haml**

```
- @skits.each do |skit|
  = render skit
```

**_skit.html.haml**

```
.votes
  - method = current_user.liked?(skit) ? :delete : :post
  = link_to like_skit_path(skit), method: method, remote: true, id: "post-#{skit.id}" do
    .upvote
      %span.upvote-link
        %i.fa.fa-caret-up
      .vote-count= skit.votes_for.size
```

**like.js.erb**

```
$("#post-<%= @skit.id %>").find(".vote-count").html('<%=j @skit.votes_for.size.to_s %>');
```

I think I need to update the method every time someone clicks the button, so user can `:post` a like or `:delete` a like, but it just stays at a POST method.

Comment: So the `delete` is not working ?

Comment: @Marwen It just doesn't switch methods after a click.

Comment: Let me write the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will have to update a bit your layout.

#### skits/_skit.html.haml

```
.skit-wrapper{id: "skit-#{skit.id}"}
  =render partial: 'skits/skit_wrapper', locals: {skit: skit}
```

#### skits/_skit_wrapper.html.haml

```
.votes
  - method = current_user.liked?(skit) ? :delete : :post
  = link_to like_skit_path(skit), method: method, remote: true do
    .upvote
      %span.upvote-link
        %i.fa.fa-caret-up
      .vote-count= skit.votes_for.size
```

#### like.js.erb

```
$("#skit-<%= @skit.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'skits/skit_wrapper', locals: {skit: @skit}) %>")
```

Comment: Happy to hear that !